# Subplot of dendrograms

Tags: python, subplot, dendrogram

I am creating six different dendrograms based on linkage.  I have a for loop which loops through the six different linkage types.  I want to print out all six of the dendrograms on one plot (using subplot) but cannot figure out how to do this.  My attempt is below - with the commented-out lines being the code intended to print out the subplots.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

linkage = ['single', 'complete', 'average', 'weighted', 'centroid', 'ward']

for item in linkage:
    #for i in range(1,7):
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(X, item) 
    #plt.subplot(1,2,i)
    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
    plt.xlabel('State',size=12)
    hierarchy.dendrogram(Z,
                    leaf_rotation=90,  # rotate the labels on X-axis
                    leaf_font_size=12,
                    labels=Label)
                     
    plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering on Covid Data:' + item, size=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `plt.figure`, matplotlib will create a new figure (plot). Since this is inside your for loop, you're currently creating a new plot for each dendogram. You can move `plt.figure` outside of the for loop, but then you'll need to spend some effort placing the dendograms such that they can still be readable. I see by your code comments that you've used [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) before? Here's a way to put each dendogram in a unique subplot inside the main figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

linkage = ['single', 'complete', 'average', 'weighted', 'centroid', 'ward']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(linkage), sharey=True)
for ax, item in zip(linkage, axes): # match each linkage to a matplotlib axis
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(X, item)
    ax.set_xlabel('State', fontdict={'size':12})
    hierarchy.dendrogram(Z,
                    leaf_rotation=90,  # rotate the labels on X-axis
                    leaf_font_size=12,
                    labels=Label,
                    ax=ax  # We have to tell scipy where to draw the dendogram
                    )
                     
    ax.set_title('Hierarchical Clustering on Covid Data:' + item, fontdict={'size':20})
```